# Simple SVG with only three paths not drawn correctly in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I have the following simple SVG file that draws three diagonal lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; fill-rule:evenodd; "
viewBox="0 0 6989 5119"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

   <path fill="#000000" d="M4409 930c63,37 125,74 187,112 -1,1 -2,3 -3,4 -62,-37 -124,-74 -187,-111 1,-2 2,-3 3,-5z"/>
   <path fill="#000000" d="M4426 906c62,37 124,74 186,111 -1,2 -2,4 -3,5 -62,-37 -124,-74 -186,-111 1,-2 2,-4 3,-5z"/>
   <path fill="#000000" d="M4442 881c62,38 124,75 186,112 -1,2 -2,3 -3,5 -62,-37 -124,-74 -186,-112 1,-1 2,-3 3,-5z"/>   
</svg>
```

To display SVG in HTML file I add the following html tag:

```
<object height="1080px" type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>
```

In Firefox everything works as expected, see image below.

[image]

In Chrome there is a problem with the line in middle(see image below).

[image]

Why is this different in Chrome and Firefox? How can I get Chrome to draw line correctly?

Comment: why do you need 4 bezier to draw a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the middle line to

```
<path fill="#000000" d="M4426 906c62,37 124,74 186,111 -1,2 -2,4 -3,5 -62,-37 -124,-74 -186,-111 1,-2 2,-3 3,-5z"/>
```

It will work correctly in both browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see any difference in the path you provided, am I missing something?

Comment: @Thomas I'm so sorry, I didn't change the code. It must be -3 in the end instead of -4.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 6989 5119">
   <path fill="#000000" d="M 0 0 L 3000 3000" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
   <path fill="#000000" d="M 0 50 L 3000 3050" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
   <path fill="#000000" d="M 0 100 L 3000 3100" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rotated rectangles you are rendering using curves are slightly different shapes. Making each shape identical does not fix the issue for me on Chrome ...

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 6989 5119">
  <path d="M4409 930c62,37 124,74 186,112 -1,2 -2,3 -3,4 -62,-37 -124,-74 -186,-111 1,-2 2,-3 3,-5z"/>
  <path d="M4426 906c62,37 124,74 186,112 -1,2 -2,3 -3,4 -62,-37 -124,-74 -186,-111 1,-2 2,-3 3,-5z"/>
  <path d="M4442 881c62,37 124,74 186,112 -1,2 -2,3 -3,4 -62,-37 -124,-74 -186,-111 1,-2 2,-3 3,-5z"/>   
</svg>
```

But as others have already mentioned, this could be done using straight line segments to create rotated rectangles. This does fix it for me ...

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 6989 5119">
  <path d="M4409 930 l 187,111 -3,4 -187,-111 z"/>
  <path d="M4426 906 l 187,111 -3,4 -187,-111 z"/>
  <path d="M4442 881 l 187,111 -3,4 -187,-111 z"/>   
</svg>
```

But we can do better by replacing the rectangles with lines (note no closing line with `z`) ... though this may not fit your requirements

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 6989 5119" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5">
  <path d="M4409 930 l -187,-111"/>
  <path d="M4426 906 l -187,-111"/>
  <path d="M4442 881 l -187,-111"/>   
</svg>
```

Note ... outside of the scope of your question but you also are using a HUGE canvas ... is thousands of pixels correct?